# CakePHP sitemap error

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, sitemap

I need to automatic generate sitemaps by using CakePHP. I followed this tutorial:
http://designaeon.com/blog/2012/07/cakephp-xml-sitemap-generation/
step by step, but my http://mysite123.com/sitemap.xml only shows me following error:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

My code looks like this:

**Controller/SitemapsController.php:**

```
 <?php
        class SitemapsController extends AppController{ 
            var $name = 'Sitemaps';
            var $uses = array('Video');

            function index(){   
                $this->set('videos', $this->Video->find('all'));
                Configure::write ('debug', 0);
            }

       } 
    ?>
```

**View/Sitemaps/xml/index.ctp:**

```
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
        <?php foreach ($videos as $vid): ?>
        <url>
            <loc><?php echo Router::url('/',true); ?>post/
                <?php echo $vid['Video']['id'];?></loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>1.0</priority>
        </url>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </urlset>
```

**View/Layouts/xml/default.ctp:**

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); ?> 
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

**routes.php**:

```
Router::parseExtensions('xml'); 
Router::connect('/sitemap', array('controller' => 'sitemaps', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: You should focus entirely on the rendered xml (which is not in the question). When you _know_ why it's invalid - then look at why your code is generating it like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685893/xml-declaration-allowed-only-at-the-start-of-the-document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend putting this in your Controller's action instead of setting the header value using PHP in your layout:

```
$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
```

It's the real 'Cake' way of doing it, and should solve your problem (which is probably whitespace or something being output before the header).

Of course, you need to be using the `RequestHandler` component, so put this in the controller if you don't already have it:

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
```